# How to remove the theme from a cms page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

I am trying to create a cms page that only includes the header and the footer. The rest of the content in the middle I code. Right now there are a bunch of divs that have a width limitation being put in there by the theme. I would like to remove them. Whether it is the div that is removed or the class I am ok with. I have tried to see what I can do with layout xml but that seems to only let me remove blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and used this- http://www.implementek.com/adding-new-page-layout-for-magento-cms-pages/

I copied the 1 column layout and removed the two classes. Then used the above to make it available on the front end.